# How to access a user's digital certificates through a web page hosted on windows server 2016 with c # .net

Tags: c#, .net

That's part of the code in localhost it works fine but on the server it doesn't work:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
```

Comment: Simple answer is that you cannot. To trigger a client certificate prompt, your server side should return a 403.7 response, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: Hi, I removed three tags that aren't *directly* related to this problem. Please take care not to "spam" tags in the future.